# Chome API - get rendered page source

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

First of all this is my first contact with javascript and so be alert...noob around.

I want my javascript to "get" the rendered page source including any frames (like in the dev tools window) and store it in a variable.

Can you point me at a way to do this? It would be very appreciated since it is the starting point for my extension.

Many thanks

Comment: At the basic level, "document.documentElement.outerHTML". This won't process IFrames, though; that may in fact require some functionality specifically available to extensions, as the browser's cross-origin policy will prevent in-site scripts from directly accessing frame contents.

Comment: Yes, but it is not easy to find the proper function on chrome's api documentation and it seems there is also some lack of questions regarding this on stackoverflow.
Thanks anyway

Comment: @user2574761 your question is one part Chrome Extension, one part plain JavaScript. Look for questions about running content scripts with a Chrome extension and for JavaScript questions around getting the content of a page. The `chrome.*` APIs are unlikely to have methods for exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://api.jquery.com/html/ to get the html contents of any element. Run .html() on the highest level element you want to get all source code inside.

eg:

var myHTML = $('my-container').html();

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for a way to use the chrome api to get the rendered page source of the current opened page. To get the source code as it is displayed in the dev tools window.